# Kafka Mirror Maker (Multiple Sources --> One Target) possible?

Tags: apache-kafka

short question to the Kafka Pros out there. I have multiple datacenters **DC_REMOTE_1**, **DC_REMOTE_2** and **DC_LOCAL**, where the remote datacenters are actually sending messages to one topic.

In the local datacenter (**DC_LOCAL**) we are running a mirror-maker which currently transfers the remote topic (**events@dc_remote_1**) to the local topic (**events@dc_local**). Is is possible to configure mirror maker in that way, that (**events@dc_remote_2**) are as well copied to the **events@local**?

It's kind of merging different remote topics into one local topic, or do we run into problems due to the offset management?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on similar requirement where you could have one independent MirrorMaker run in each DC (DC_REMOTE_1 and DC_REMOTE_2) which will act as a consumer for the local kafka clusters and send the data to DC_LOCAL(this way there are no issues on offset management).
Indeed the capacity of the kafka cluster DC_LOCAL should be approximately 2 times the DC_REMOTE_1/2 kafka clusters.

Let me know if this helps your requirement.